# css: изменение положения всех элементов, вместо изменения положения одного элемента

Tags: html, css, list, menu, position

Подскажите пожалуйста, с чем может быть дело:
Реализовал меню, выбранный (для удобства сделал не выбранный, а наведенный) элемент изменяет свое положение. И вместо того, чтобы измениться только положение одного элемента, меняются все.

Как это можно исправить?  (хотелось бы остаться в рамках ul li)

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5zphj2pj/)

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.menu {
  user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  -o-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 0px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #0090d0;
  text-align: left;
}


/* выпадающее меню */

.dropdown-menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 100px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-size: 0px;
  z-index: 2;
}

.dropdown-menu ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.dropdown-menu ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0px 15px;
  padding: 0px 10px;
  color: #000000;
  text-align: left;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 32px;
  font-weight: 400;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: calc(40px - 2px);
  border: 2px solid transparent;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #404040;
}

.dropdown-menu>ul>li:hover {
  margin-top: 5px;
  font-weight: 400;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
  border: 2px solid #0090d0;
  border-bottom: none;
  height: calc(40px - 5px);
}
```

```html
<div class='menu'>
  <div class='dropdown-menu'>
    <ul>
      <li>FIRST</li>
      <li>SECOND</li>
      <li>THIRD</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Комментарий прочитай в `css`

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.menu {
  user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  -o-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 0px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #0090d0;
  text-align: left;
}


/* выпадающее меню */

.dropdown-menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 100px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-size: 0px;
  z-index: 2;
}

.dropdown-menu ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  background: blue;
}

.dropdown-menu ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0px 15px;
  padding: 0px 10px;
  color: #000000;
  text-align: left;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 32px;
  font-weight: 400;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: calc(40px - 2px);
  border: 2px solid transparent;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #404040;
  background: green;
}

.dropdown-menu ul li:hover {
  /*ты менял margin а он воздействет и на остальные элементы*/
  top: 5px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 32px;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
  border: 2px solid #0090d0;
  border-bottom: none;
  height: calc(40px - 5px);
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class='menu'>
  <div class='dropdown-menu'>
    <ul>
      <li>FIRST</li>
      <li>SECOND</li>
      <li>THIRD</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Если хочется, чтобы он сдвигался вниз, можно добавить

```
vertical-align: top;
```

потому что по умолчанию используется `baseline`, что означает, что все элементы выравниваются так, чтобы нижняя линяя текста у них совпадала.

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.menu {
  user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  -o-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 0px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #0090d0;
  text-align: left;
}


/* выпадающее меню */

.dropdown-menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 100px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-size: 0px;
  z-index: 2;
}

.dropdown-menu ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.dropdown-menu ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0px 15px;
  padding: 0px 10px;
  color: #000000;
  text-align: left;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 32px;
  font-weight: 400;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: calc(40px - 2px);
  border: 2px solid transparent;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #404040;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.dropdown-menu>ul>li:hover {
  margin-top: 5px;
  font-weight: 400;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
  border: 2px solid #0090d0;
  border-bottom: none;
  height: calc(40px - 5px);
}
```

```html
<div class='menu'>
  <div class='dropdown-menu'>
    <ul>
      <li>FIRST</li>
      <li>SECOND</li>
      <li>THIRD</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Ещё один косяк - margin. Если навести мышку на верхнюю часть блока - выше границы при hover'е, то элемент начнёт мерцать.

В большинстве случаев правильным будет сделать постоянную границу и просто менять ей цвет с прозрачного на синий.